# How to layout boolean combinatorics system with dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a problem with layout in Graphviz. I looking for a somewhat general way to have the inbound edges to enter a node evenly spread out on the left side and exit from the middle of the right side.

In short I want to make something like this,

[image: goal]

But instead my markup generates this

[image: current]

from this code

```
graph g {
  splines=ortho;
  nodesep=0.005 
  rankdir="LR";

  node [shape=box width=.5];

  x  [shape=none];
  y1 [label="y" shape=none];
  y2 [label="y" shape=none];
  z  [shape=none];
  f  [label="f(x,y,z)" shape=none];

  A [label="&"];
  B [label="1" ];
  C [label="&" ];
  D [label="≥1"];

  x  -- A;
  y1 -- A;
  A  -- D;
  y2 -- B;
  B  -- C [arrowtail="odot"];
  z  -- C;
  C  -- D;
  D  -- f;

  { rank=same; x y1 y2 z }
  { rank=same; A B }
  { rank=same; C }
  { rank=same; D }
  { rank=same; f }
}
```

I've experimented with the splines, nodsep and pos attributes neither made  an acceptable result.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) would be the solution. Unfortunately [ports](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#kportPos) do not work with `splines=ortho` ([issue](http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=1992)) and splines do not look great on logic charts. This port/ortho bug also applies to record shape nodes. So basically you are lost.

```
digraph logic { rankdir=LR
    node [shape=plaintext]
    nand [label=<
        <TABLE CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR>
                <TD><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0">
                    <TR><TD BORDER="0" PORT="1">1</TD></TR>
                    <TR><TD BORDER="0" PORT="2">2</TD></TR>
                </TABLE></TD>
                <TD BORDER="0" PORT="out">&amp;</TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>>];
    1 -> nand:1:w [dir=none]
    2 -> nand:2:w [dir=none]
    nand:out:e -> out [dir=back arrowtail=odot]
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's too bad, maybe I should look at tikz instead